# citep with comments inside

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I have the following code

```
"...random graphs \citep{er1959,g1959,b2001}..."
```

which produces

```
"random graphs (Erdos and Renyi, 1959; Gilbert, 1959; Bollobás, 2001)"
```

I would like it to produce:

```
"random graphs (Erdos and Renyi, 1959; Gilbert, 1959; for a textbook treatment see Bollobás, 2001)"
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do this with a single `\cite` command, since there is no way to attach the extra text to one part of a multiple part citation.  So the only way to do it is manually, using the `\citealp` macro (which gives you a `\citep` without the parentheses) and add the parentheses yourself.

```
... random graphs
        (\citealp{er1959,g1959}; \citealp[for a textbook treatment see ][]{b2001})
```